# Simplify long expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, fractions

I am trying to show that when inserting $$S = Q \frac{hd + pb}{bh + pb}$$ into the expression $$\frac{h(bS - dQ)^2}{2b(b-d)Q} + \frac{pb(Q-S)^2}{2(b-d)Q}$$ it can be simplified to the fraction $$\frac{hp(b-d)Q}{2(h+p)b}.$$

However, when I first insert $S$ into the expression and start expanding and get a very long a complex expression with lots of quadratic terms. Are there any tricks so to speak that can make this simplification easier? Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rewrite the first equation 
\begin{eqnarray*}
S=Q\frac{pb+\color{red}{bh-bh}+hd}{b(h+p)}=Q\frac{\color{blue}{pb+bh}-bh+hd}{b(h+p)}=Q \left(\color{blue}{1}+\frac{h(d-b)}{b(h+p)} \right)  \\
bS= Q \left(d+ \frac{p(b-d)}{h+p} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
Now sub into the expression
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{h(bS-dQ)^2}{2b(b-d)Q}+\frac{pb(Q-S)^2}{2(b-d)Q} &=&Q \frac{hp^2(b-d)^2}{2b(b-d)(h+p)^2} +\frac{Qpbh^2(b-d)^2}{2(b-d)b^2(h+p)^2}  \\
&=& \frac{Qhp}{2b(h+p)^2} \left(p(b-d)+h(b-d) \right) \\
&=& \frac{Qhp(b-d)}{2b(h+p)} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: +0.5 for observation and +0.5 for patience.

Comment: @samjoe Thank you ... The whole is more than the sum of the parts. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thank you. I am not familiar with the rule you are using when you rewrite the equations in the first step. Could you please tell me what rule it is?

Comment: I have put in some more explanation for the first equation, you can do the second one in a similar way.

Answer (score 4):

Pull a factor $b$ out of the global expression and the numerator is

$$h(S-\frac db Q)^2+p(Q-S)^2.$$

Then omitting the factor $Q$,

$$ \frac{hd + pb}{bh + pb}-\frac db=\frac{p(b-d)}{b(h+p)}$$
and
$$1-\frac{hd + pb}{bh + pb}=\frac{h(b-d)}{b(h+p)}.$$

Now the expression is

$$b\frac{(hp^2+ph^2)\dfrac{(b-d)^2}{b^2(h+p)^2}}{2(b-d)}\frac{Q^2}Q=\frac{hp(b-d)}{2b(h+p)}Q.$$